# Error in jquery ajax() method?

Tags: jquery

To redirect current page I use `window.document.location()` statement inside the `ajax()` function. But it is showing error(in firebug). There is no error in functionality request is going and response is comming properly. `window.document.location('user/index.php');` statement creating the problem. How can I redirect this page to another if the `msg=='YES'`?

```
$.ajax({
          url:  "user_registration.php",
          type: "post",
          data: datastring,
          success: function(msg) {
              if(msg=='YES') {                                  
                   window.document.location('user/index.php');
              }
              else
                   $("#success").html(msg);
        }
   });
```

Comment: Don't you mean document.location.href = 'user/index.php' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply say `window.location = newLocation;` in your success handler to redirect to new location.

```
$.ajax ({
     url:  "user_registration.php",
     type: "post",
     data: datastring,
     success: function(msg) {
          if(msg=='YES') {                                  
               window.location = 'user/index.php';
          }
          else {
           $("#success").html(msg);
          }
     }
});
```

More on `window.location` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.location).

Answer (score 0):

should the relative URL be "/user/index.php" ?

Comment: Then it becomes absolute (starting at the current domain name)

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location.href = 'user/index.php';
```

don't forget, YES must be YES, not yes

Answer (score 0):

Use `window.location.replace("http://www.w3schools.com")` that should work.

For more information check out the [w3schools page on this topic](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp)